# Add UITextField to UIAlertView in C#

Tags: c#, iphone, visual-studio-2012, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to add two textfields in a UIAlertView but I can't see any obvious way to do it?
I can add only one text field using the code below:

```
popupAlert.AlertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.PlainTextInput;
```

but when I try to add another one nothings happens, only one appears.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIAlertView has a built in style for logins that has two text fields.  You can override it's default behavior to change the password field into a normal input.

```
    UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView ();

    alert.AlertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.LoginAndPasswordInput;
    alert.Title = "Alert";
    alert.GetTextField (1).SecureTextEntry = false;
    alert.GetTextField (1).Placeholder = "Input 2";
    alert.GetTextField (0).Placeholder = "Input 1";

    alert.Show ();
```